# SharePoint_Config_Log fast increase in size

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, database

the SharePoint_Config_Log size is taking a lot of space really fast i need to make stop at least make go slower. am i missing anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you navigate to Central Administration >> Monitoring >> Reporting: Configure Diagnostic Logging. You can configure logging to be less verbose, turn off logging for features you may not need, and limit the amount of space it consumes.

See this link for a reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748656(v=office.15).aspx